# Is there a way to connect to iBeacon while my Bluetooth device is invisible?

Tags: bluetooth, ibeacon

I'm researching iBeacons. Can I connect to iBeacons while my Bluetooth is invisible (to be protected from hacks)?

I don't have beacons to test myself and can't find any clear explanation online.

Comment: When you say "bluetooth is invisible" are you referring to your mobile phone having bluetooth disabled?

Comment: Yes I want to open my phone's Bluetooth connection as **invisible** to public. I want to share my phone's Bluetooth visibility only to the beacons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just bought some beacons and tested that, The answer is **YES**. it is possible to read beacons mac addresses while using the phone's Bluetooth connection as invisible. Using this you will get access to your beacon in any open place without getting hacked through Bluetooth.

Thanks all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

iBeacons connect to mobile phones using Bluetooth, so it is essential to have that turned on. You also need to have installed an app with iBeacon support in order to receive communication from them.

If you'd wish to use a solution that does not utilize Bluetooth, you could try out [IndoorAtlas](http://indooratlas.com). It's an indoor navigation technology based on Earth's geomagnetic fields. It's also completely hardware-free solution, just requires you to collect fingerprints in the area you are going to use for your project.

Comment: Thanks @Annina. I want to know what about opening the Bluetooth connection in my phone and mark Bluetooth connection to be **invisible** to others. Can I connect to IBeacons in case I know their Mac address and if I'm invisible?

Answer (score 0):

Three points:

- iBeacon technology does not rely on a bluetooth connection to your phone.  Beacons are one way transmitters.  They do not listen to or otherwise receive any info from your device.  Beacon technology following this model is inherently privacy friendly.
- Mobile devices cannot detect Bluetooth beacons with the Bluetooth radio turned off.  Sorry, it is just not possible.
- Properly built beacon apps will not expose your mobile device's Bluetooth info because they are receive only.  Of course, other apps on your phone might use bluetooth for other purposes, so your best bet is to audit apps using bluetooth and remove any that are not doing what you want.